# Multiple Launch image of iOS

Tags: ios, image, launch

My app has a Terms & Conditions page. It is visible first time after app install. After accept terms it never shows to user.

I have make Launch image for first page, not for terms page. But it should be not standard for first time after app install.

1. So how I can use 2 launch image based on condition?
2. If I set Portrait mode only for my app (for both iPhone and iPad), Apple will reject that?

Comment: For first time display, write code in `AppDelegate` in method `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Comment: how it is possible, I got that changing launch image with programatically is not possible. Please explain..

Comment: As `Nguyen Duc` say , create separate `UIViewController` for your 2 images and then go for regular Root `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this this way:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // ... stuff

    if( [defaults objectForKey:@"GTCAccepted"] )
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(gtcAccepted)]; //
    }
    else
    {
        GTCViewController* gtcViewController; // where GTCViewController is a normal UIViewController

        //universal app
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            gtcViewController = [[GTCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GTCViewController-iPad" bundle:nil];
        else
            gtcViewController = [[GTCViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GTCViewController" bundle:nil];

        [window setRootViewController:gtcViewController]; // also can show as modal VC
        [gtcViewController release];

        // if accepted, set [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"GTCAccepted"]; in the GTCViewController
    }
}
```

and to your 2 launch images...

try this code after accepting the GTC

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"GTCAccepted"];

NSURL *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Default-568h@2x_2" withExtension:@"png"];
NSURL *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Default-568h@2x" withExtension:@"png"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:path error:nil]; // permission denied

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:path2 toURL:path error:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"startItem replaced!");
}else
{
    NSLog(@"oh oh... item not replaced!");
}
```

*UPDATE:*
*Code doesn't work on device, see permission denied on delete*

By the way, if you run in always on simulator starting with Xcode, you will override this every time you run. and here you have no chance to change the image before the app starts.

Comment: Thanks!, but how Default-568h@2x_2 will be call as we are using Default-568h@2x for launch image. And I need to replace all sizes launch images. Please let me inform your thought.

Comment: you add the Default-568h@2x_2 as a simple image to your target as all other resolutions too (hope you know how to add existing files to your project :P). If the image is in you bundle, you have full access to it. and if you need to replace all, so feel free to do so ^^ just copy-paste the upper part or loop them, it's your decision :)

Comment: Have you checked this in devices and also Apple approve this?

Comment: I don't think that apple would reject this (worth a try :P) but I just tried the theory on a device, and there I got "permission denied" :/ too bad, now it's only left to change backgounds and not the launch-screen :(

Comment: Then this is not Marked Answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30382/discussion-between-geo-and-user748178)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should not using 2 launch image. If you want to check image based on condition, you can use a view controller to show, animation it and go to to next screen. Launch image only one. we can't access it.
2. Only portrait for both iPhone and iPad will not reject.

Comment: Thanks! , you are saying that every time app will show first screen instead of terms screen. And if it first time after install, app will navigate from first screen to terms screen through an animation? Please let me inform details.

Comment: Is it ok to have just one launch image say LaunchImage@3x.png in your project, will apple reject my app because of not providing other configuration images, the reason why I wanna do is because my image is of around 25 KB.